# BITWISE Operator usage

Tags: c

```
if (!(y&1))

    {

        c[x++]=d[--y];

    }
```

I am unable to understand what this statement does. y is a int value.

what is the not (!) sign for?

Comment: Hint: What's the result of `y & 1`? When will the `if` be satisfied?

Comment: `!` is an unary operator, so-called **not**. Do googling about C operators unary/bitwise ones

Answer (score 2):

The `!` transforms `0` to `1` and everything else to `0`.

The `y&1` results in `0` if the latest bit of `y` is `0` (that is `y` is a power of `2`):

```
......0
0000001
-------
0000000
```

versus

```
......1
0000001
-------
0000001
```

So, the `if` simply tests if `y` is a <del>power</del>multiple of 2.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The condition is true when the number y is even, and false when the number y is odd.

The expression

```
y & 1
```

means bitwise AND of an integer y and 1. The result is effectively equal to the least significant bit of y. Odd numbers have theit last bit set to one; for even numbers, the last bit is always zero.

Adding a NOT ! operator inverts that bit.